# how to set parent forum link to menu page?

Tags: plugins, bbpress, forum

I have installed `bbforum` on my wordpress website. I want to set main forum page to be displayed on MENU `FORUM` How can I set that?

My parent link is `http://www.demoweb.com/forums/`

Also I want to give rights to create a forum topics to all user?

Answer (score 1):

To display a link to the Forum page in your menu, you should be able [to add it in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen#Add_Menu_Items) the Menu editor.

To change the default forum role of new users, go into Settings->Forum, and change the **Auto Role** to the [one you want](http://codex.bbpress.org/bbpress-user-roles-and-capabilities/).